# How to add HemisphereLight to a simple threejs scene?

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js, scene

I'm trying to add light and see its changes in a simple scene in threejs but no matter the intensity or the color I set for the light, I see no change. Actually, if I don't include the light code, nothing changes as well, so why is HemisphereLight not working in my case?

```
  var scene = new THREE.Scene();
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 200, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

  var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(25, 60, 20, 20);

  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:"green"})

  var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
  var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x000000, 2);

  scene.add(light);
  scene.add(plane);

  plane.rotateZ(Math.PI/2)
  camera.position.z = 10;

  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

  var render = function (time) {
              requestAnimationFrame( render );   
       
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();
```

Comment: `MeshBasicMaterial` does not respond to lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Three.JS do you use?

I made a JSFiddle with your code, using only Javascript and Three.js version 105 and everything worked, when I used Three.JS version r54, it indeed didn't work.

Sorry that I ask this question like this, can't comment yet haha.
I'll remove this if asked

You can check what version you're using with:

```
console.log(THREE. REVISION)
```

```html
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script> 
    <script type="module">
    console.log(THREE. REVISION)

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 200, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(25, 60, 20, 20);

        var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:"green"})

        var plane = new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
        var light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x000000, 2);

        scene.add(light);
        scene.add(plane);

        plane.rotateZ(Math.PI/2)
        camera.position.z = 10;

        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffff00);

        var render = function (time) {
                    requestAnimationFrame( render );   
            
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };
            render();
    </script>
```

All of this goes into 1 HTML File.

Comment: It logs 143 when I include this code.

Comment: @Jonas I've made a new HTML, with exactly the same code as yours, only difference is that I changed the color from the background to yellow instead of white and that I use Three.JS version 146 by importing it with "<script src="...."></script>", but everything seems working just fine, so not sure what could be the issue, i'll update my answer here above with the code, so that you can take a look at it. You could copy it to your code and see if it works.

Comment: I've used your snippet and noticed that no matter the value of intensity, or the colors for the lights, the result is exactly the same. I've experimented with many colors and many intensity values and the look of your image is the same. Why is that so?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I see that @WestLangley commented the answer under your main question, it's because of the type of material that you use, you can read more about materials in this [article](https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-materials.html)